# kube-prometheus-stack's alertmanager configs are empty but pod config was populated

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager, kube-prometheus-stack

I'm trying to enable alertmanager in my cluster and have a config that passes `amtool config-check` and doesn't generate any errors when applied (nothing in the operator pod's log). The config is in the main kube-prometheus-stack CRD:

```
  kube-prometheus-stack:
  [...]
  alertmanager:
    enabled: true
    alertManagerSpec:
      secrets: pagerduty
    config:
      global:
      [...]
```

I exec'ed into the alertmanager pod and see my config got there correctly. But the alertmanager CRDs don't seem to have changed at all:

```
$ kubectl -n mynamespace get alertmanagerconfigs.monitoring.coreos.com -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items: []
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

Some things to note:

- both prometheus and alertmanager are in the same mynamespace
- I haven't created any actual alerts yet
- my root level receiver doesn't do anything, I have child receivers configured tho

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the logs of prometheus-operator and you might need to increase the logging.  I had issues with my config and it only ever show in those logs

Comment: Thanks, nothing really helpful there unfortunately. I had the same result with a simpler example config.

Comment: by any chance you have any luck with this, I am now having a similar issue and logs don't show anything :(

Comment: It turns out that this was working fine and the `alertmanagerconfigs` CRD will not reflect this configuration. I guess you'd have to create `alertmanagerconfigs` separately and have the config selector set to pick that up.

Comment: You can also try running your config through the `amtool` config check option.